# Append Lines on Unix from File1, File2 into File3 based on the Column value in a specific sort order

Tags: awk, grep

I have been searching over the web for a week now and I can't seem to find any solution that works for the scenario I have.  I have two files.

File1 contains a number of columns but the last column is the reference number. And will be used as the driving file.

File1 contents:

```
file1abc|file1abc|file1123|9999999    
file1def|file1def|file1456|8888888
```

File2 contains many columns as well but the reference number repeats and there's a required sort field

File2 contents

```
file2xyz|file2xyz|file2987|sort1|9999999
file2qrs|file2qrs|file2765|sort2|8888888
file2efg|file2efg|file2555|sort3|9999999
file2tuv|file2tuv|file2666|sort2|9999999
file2xyz|file2xyz|file2987|sort1|8888888
```

Desired Results to output.

File1 lines will be the initial line followed by file2 lines where the reference number match and sorted by the column with the sort #

output to contain

```
file1abc|file1abc|file1123|9999999
file2xyz|file2xyz|file2987|sort1|9999999
file2efg|file2efg|file2555|sort2|9999999
file2tuv|file2tuv|file2666|sort3|9999999
file1def|file1def|file1456|8888888
file2qrs|file2qrs|file2765|sort1|8888888
file2xyz|file2xyz|file2987|sort2|8888888
```

Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: That "sort" field being alphanumeric creates a problem that won't become obvious until your sample input contains values like `sort10` because it won't sort correctly numerically as it starts with letters and it won't sort correctly alphabetically because alphabetically `sort10` comes before `sort2`, not after it. It's not hard to address but the currently posted answers don't account for that because your sample input/output doesn't cover that case - you should fix your example to include that case when you add your own attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly straightforward if you have a suitably recent version of GNU awk, using a 2D array and `PROCINFO` to set the array traversal globally to use the **str**ing (i.e. lexical) value of the **ind**ex in **asc**ending order:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN {FS = "|"; PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"} 
  NR==FNR {a[$NF][$(NF-1)] = $0; next} 
  {print; for(i in a[$NF]) print a[$NF][i]}
' File2 File1
file1abc|file1abc|file1123|9999999
file2xyz|file2xyz|file2987|sort1|9999999
file2tuv|file2tuv|file2666|sort2|9999999
file2efg|file2efg|file2555|sort3|9999999
file1def|file1def|file1456|8888888
file2xyz|file2xyz|file2987|sort1|8888888
file2qrs|file2qrs|file2765|sort2|8888888
```

With older GNU awk, you can use `asorti` to achieve the same:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN{FS="|"} 
  NR==FNR {a[$NF][$(NF-1)] = $0; next} 
  {print; n = asorti(a[$NF],dst,"@ind_str_asc"); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[$NF][dst[i]]}
' File2 File1
```

If you want to sort *numerically* based on some substring of the `(NF-1)`th field, then you can change `@ind_str_asc` to `@ind_num_asc` and replace `$(NF-1)` as the second array index by a suitably preprocessed value ex.

```
substr($(NF-1),5)
```

or using a regular expression (for more complex key extraction)

```
gensub(/[^0-9]*([0-9]+)$/,"\\1","1",$(NF-1))
```

With other awks, you could use 1D array and an external sort:

```
mawk '
  BEGIN {FS="|"; cmd = "sort -t \| -k4"}
  NR==FNR {a[$NF] = a[$NF] (a[$NF]=="" ? "" : ORS) $0; next}
  {print; print a[$NF] | cmd; close(cmd)}' File2 File1
file1abc|file1abc|file1123|9999999
file2xyz|file2xyz|file2987|sort1|9999999
file2tuv|file2tuv|file2666|sort2|9999999
file2efg|file2efg|file2555|sort3|9999999
file1def|file1def|file1456|8888888
file2xyz|file2xyz|file2987|sort1|8888888
file2qrs|file2qrs|file2765|sort2|8888888
```

Here, your sort options will be limited to the options supported by the external `sort` function, ex. `cmd = "sort -t \| -k4.5,4n"` will sort numerically based on the 5th character onward of the 4th field.